# Mod_fcgid Internal Server Error and No Confirmation Page with Confirmed Stripe Payment on Wordpress WooCommerce Site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, mod-fcgid

Upon placing a credit card error on vabienusa.com, I get an "Internal Service Error" while the payment is successful via Stripe Dashboard leaving users without a confirmation page.

Upshot link: https://www.upwork.com/jobs/~012ce3987bb1ae4031

**Server Error Logs:**

*Note:URL shortened to because of StackOverlfow limit on URLS*

> [warn] [client 64.80.129.250] (104)Connection reset by peer:
>   mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: /checkout/
>
> [error] [client 64.80.129.250] Premature end of script headers: php,
>   referer: checkout/
>
> [emerg] [client 64.80.129.250] (22)Invalid argument: mod_fcgid: can’t
>   lock process table in pid 497662, referer: /checkout/
>
> [emerg] [client 64.80.129.250] (22)Invalid argument: mod_fcgid: can’t
>   lock process table in pid 548206, referer:
>   /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-status&tab=logs&w3tc_note=flush_pgcache
>
> [emerg] [client 196.42.9.89] (22)Invalid argument: mod_fcgid: can’t
>   lock process table in pid 577444, referer:
>   /wp-admin/post.php?post=907&action=edit

**What I Have Done to Attempt to Resolve Error:**

- MySql 8 updated to MySql 10
- PHP memory limit updated
- Moved to new server so PHP updated to 5.6 per Wordpress' requirements
- Enabled force HTTPS and HTTP on exit of checkout
- Deactivated force HTTPS

**Notes:**

- We do not use other payment gateways
- Have yet to get a confirmation page, this is a new site and not yet marketed
- We can confirm the order and payment goes through Stripe
- There are no Wordpress Log Errors, only logs of successful payments

Comment: This might be a bug with FCGID. Can you try upgrading Apache and mod_fcgid to the latest available versions?

Answer (score 0):

We found that the Wordpress site was not using SMTP authentication and thus sendmail process caused a server error. So, I installed ‘Easy WP SMTP’ plugin.